# The following WSDL exception occurred: WSDLException: faultCode=WSDL4JWrapper

Tags: java, websphere

I´m trying to connect to a webService on a Java application. I create my own .jks file for the certificates.
When I deploy the app in my local (is a tomcat server), the application is ok. But when I deploy it on a Websphere server I have this error:

`The following WSDL exception occurred: WSDLException: faultCode=WSDL4JWrapper : : javax.wsdl.WSDLException: WSDLException: faultCode=WSDL4JWrapper : : javax.net.ssl.SSLException: SSLSocketFactory is null. This can occur if javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.getDefault() is called to create a socket and javax.net.ssl.* properties are not set.`

I set the properties on this way:

```
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", this.util.getPropertie("trustStore"));
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", this.util.getPropertie("trustStorePassword"));
System.setProperty( "javax.net.ssl.keyStore", this.util.getPropertie("keyStore"));
System.setProperty( "javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword", this.util.getPropertie("keyStorePassword"));
```

And I take the properties from a .properties file.

Thanks in advance. I apologize if I didn´t do my question correctly, but is my first time writing here.

Regards.

I´m trying to connect my web application to a web service

Comment: Is this traditional Websphere or WebSphere Liberty (i.e. What version of WebSphere are you on?) I ask because if it's WebSphere Liberty, you are using, it would help to see how you have you features configured in your sever.xml.

Answer (score 0):

In WAS traditional, the SSL configurations that you define in the administrative console are applied at the runtime by a class called an SSLSocketFactory. WebSphere has its own custom SSLSocketFactory implementation (com.ibm.websphere.ssl.protocol.SSLSocketFactory) which it sets as the default for the IBM Java runtime that it sits on top of. When application code calls APIs that use this SSLSocketFactory for their connections, the WAS SSL settings are applied to the connection and any problems with the connection (for example protocol mismatches, cipher suite mismatches, or certificate trust issues) can be resolved by making changes to the SSL configurations in the WAS administrative console.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fxET5.png)
Suppose you explicitly use system properties within your code rather than relying on the default settings configured for the JVM (which, in typical scenarios, is the WebSphere Application Server (WAS) implementation). In that case, it may bypass the WAS SSL configuration, including settings such as keyStores, trustStores, cipher suites, and handshake protocols.

if you choose to override the WAS SSL settings, please ensure that you include the system properties for the keystore type and truststore type, which are set as follows:

```
javax.net.ssl.trustStoreType
javax.net.ssl.keyStoreType
```

Both of these properties should be set to JKS.

If you have any further questions or need additional assistance from WAS SSL, please do not hesitate to contact IBM Websphere technical support.

Comment: This seems to be a straight up copy&paste, low effort answer. Please at least fix the image alt and remove the websphere technical support phrase.